# Data not sent to Kafka with Avro serialization

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, avro4s

I'm trying to send data to Kafka with Avro, but the "messages" remain empty. I tried to add the schema to Kafka manually, but to no result. I don't see any errors in the logs of my application, in the schema-registry logs, or in Kafka's logs.  Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{ KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord, RecordMetadata }
import com.sksamuel.avro4s.{ AvroSchema, Record, RecordFormat, SchemaFor }    

case class User(name: String, age: Int)

val connectConfig: Map[String, Object] =
Map(
  "bootstrap.servers"   -> "localhost:9092",
  "client.id"           -> s"clientID${UUID.randomUUID().toString}",
  "key.serializer"      -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
  "value.serializer"    -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer",
  "schema.registry.url" -> "localhost:8081"
)

implicit val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, Record](connectConfig.asJava)

def sendAvro(msg: DIL): Future[RecordMetadata] = {
    val newUser = User("Joe", 42)
    val schema  = AvroSchema[User]
    implicit val schemaFor = SchemaFor[User]
    val format = RecordFormat[User]

    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, Record]("kafkaLogTopic", format.to(newUser))
    producer.send(record)
}
```

Comment: Looks like this code never actually calls `sendAvro` method.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka sends data in batches, and your single record is smaller than the default batch size.

Use `.send(data).get()` or `producer.flush()` to immediately wait on one record to be sent.

Otherwise, you should define a thread on `scala.sys.ShutdownHookThread` to flush the producer

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you actually calling sendAvro? Otherwise, since that function returns a Future, you would really need to do `sendAvro().get()`, or also `producer.flush`